# Capture soft keyboard events on Nexus 7 (Android 4.2)

Tags: android, keyboard, nexus-7

I would like to catch the press of any key of the soft keyboard. At least Enter & Backspace keys.

I've tried:

1. `OnKeyListener` for EditText
2. `onKeyDown` for Activity
3. `dispatchKeyEvent` for Activity
4. `onEditorAction` for my custom EditText

Nothing works. Yes, I know that all these methods are guaranteed for hardware key events only but what do I have to do to know that the Enter(for example) was pressed in this case?

Comment: Did you override onKeyDown?  Show us some code...